# Parse data from watson

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

Hi there i'm using Watson speech to text and everything go well, i set up a timeout and then print what i'm saying. My next goal is to parse in real time what i'm saying and when I, for example, say "stop" i stop the recognize stream.

The code is:

```
const recognizeStream = speechToText.createRecognizeStream({
  content_type: 'audio/wav',
});

const micInstance = mic({
 channels: 2,
 debug: true,
 rate: '44100',
});

const wavStream = new wav.Writer({
 channels: 2,
 sampleRate: 44100
});

const micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();

micInputStream.on('data', (_data) => {
 console.log('Recieve Input Stream: ' + _data.length);
});

micInputStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Error in Input Stream: ' + err);
});

micInputStream.on('startComplete', () => {
  console.log('Got SIGNAL startComplete');
   setTimeout(() => {
     micInstance.stop();
  }, 5000);
});

micInputStream.on('silence', () => {
    console.log('Got SIGNAL silence');
});

micInputStream.on('processExitComplete', () => {
   console.log('Got SIGNAL processExitComplete');
});

micInputStream.pipe(wavStream);
wavStream.pipe(recognizeStream);

// process.stdin.resume();
recognizeStream.on('end', () => {
     process.exit();
});

recognizeStream.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('data: ', data.toString());
});
micInstance.start();
```

Is this possibile?

Comment: It seems to be that you just need to unsubscribe from a stream on 'stop'. What problem do you have?

Comment: I receive data after stop, my goal is receive data when i speak

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Define a boolean variable isDataReceived, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you will face here is latency. ie. the time lag between you saying 'stop' and your application realising that 'stop' has been requested, and closing the stream.

When you say 'stop' that part of the stream has to be transferred to service in the cloud; The service performs its speech to text operations, on speech uttered before, during, and after the 'stop'; The service sends the transcription back to the application. The application realises that 'Stop' has been requested. In the meantime the application has continued to stream audio up to the service.

Comment: There is any solutions?